# Change image by Variation name woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using the below code for my store single page sidebar, I set image by variation name (type-2).

```
function image_by_variation() {global $product;if ( ! $product->get_attribute( 'type-2' )) return;echo '<div class="var_img"><img src="image1" height="200" width="500"></div>';}
```

screenshot - https://prnt.sc/o__rry_OT4g5
Now my type-2 variation has two items,

1. repaired
2. never-repaired

I want to change the image banner by variation. Becouse I will select only one variation for one product. some time (repaired) sometimes (never repaired)

Like--> if select repaired (image1), or select never-repaired (image2)

Comment: Please provide more details, Like screenshots of the page, and on clicking what, you want to change what?

Comment: Hi, here is a screenshot for single type banner --> https://prnt.sc/nLZ3amIfJFfe
I added another type called renewed, so now i want if variable name type = renewed show renewed banner, or if selected refurbished want to show refurbished banner.

Comment: If sidebar images are going to be the same for all the products, then you need to load both images, with display: none, then you need to write jquery code, in jquery you need to do 2 things, first on the load you need to fetch the currently selected value from the dropdown and based on that show the relative image, then you need to add `change` event listener so when you change the dropdown value, you match the selected value and show hide the right side images.

Comment: here i want to show by if else only using PHP, my type variation like this- https://prnt.sc/o__rry_OT4g5
because I will select always one option for the product.

Comment: See, page content can't be changed without using javascript or jquery. as you mentioned you want show different image on changing/clicking the variation name then you need to use javascript or jquery.

Comment: but I always select only one value refurbished or renewed, no need to change or refresh the page. The code will only see which one is selected and display the banner accordingly.

Comment: You need to update your question in that case, you have already mentioned **I want to change the image by clicking the variation name.** and now you say you don't wanna change things on click on variation name. Your question is not very clear to understand what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: I updated. can help with this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```php
function image_by_variation() {
    global $product;

    // Get the type attribute and store in variable.
    $type = $product->get_attribute( 'type-2' );

    // Check if type value is empty?
    if ( empty( $type ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Compare with repaired.
    if ( 'repaired' === $type ) {
        echo '<div class="var_img"><img src="https://ksa.revent.store/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/repaired.png" height="200" width="500"></div>';
        return;
    }

    // Compare with never repaired.
    if ( 'never-repaired' === $type ) {
        echo '<div class="var_img"><img src="https://ksa.revent.store/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/never-repaired.png" height="200" width="500"></div>';
        return;
    }
}
```

Note: if `$product->get_attribute( 'type-2' )` return an array then you'll have to change conditions to check `repaired` Or `never-repaired` exists in that array or not.